# How to check the form create was closed after click on "Close" button by Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing test automation for `Create device`. I am trying to `assert` through something that to know my form closed after click on `Close` button.

I have form like this
[Create device form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjS46.png)

And this is my code for that

```
class createDevice(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/admin/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        driver = cls.driver
        driver.get("https://admin-helper-f21c1.web.app/login")
        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_email("admin@gmail.com")
        login.enter_password("123456")
        login.click_login()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_create_device_04(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sidebar"]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        create_device_form = CreateDevicePage(driver)
        create_device_form.click_create_device()
        time.sleep(3)
        create_device_form.click_close()
        //I would like to assert right here to know let me know that the test is correctly that means my form already closed
        

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
        print("Test create device completed")
```

Please help me for this, thank you all so much

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to verify form still present on html or not. If driver still find your form element then it return false, else it return true. After that using assert the method result.

Example code:

```
def is_form_close(self):
    is_form_close = True
    try:
        # locate your form by what ever you have
        driver.find_element_by_id("")
        is_form_close = False
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Form has been close")
    return is_form_close

assert is_form_close() == True
```